# Unable to install the kernel 3.5 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, kernel

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and it's kernel version is "3.8.0-29-generic". For learning purposes I want to change my kernel version from 3.8.o to 3.5.0 version, but I am unable to install it in Ubuntu 12.04.

I followed these steps for kernel compilation:

After downloading source code from kernel.org i followed these steps:

1. `tar -xvf linux-3.5.tar.xz`
2. `cd linux-3.5/`
3. `ls`
4. `make menuconfig`
5. `make -j`
6. `make modules_install`
7. `sudo make modules_install`
8. `sudo make install`
9. `make modules`
10. `sudo reboot`

After successful completion of all these steps, Ubuntu is again starting with kernel 3.8.0 generic version. How can I change it?

Comment: When you reach the stage with the GRUB2 menu, is there a choice for the older kernel? Please advise.

Comment: The grub menu is not displaying anything.after i typed the command "sudo reboot " it defaultly taking the 3.8 version and it not showing anything.

Comment: You could always try installing Ubuntu 12.10, I think that had 3.5 kernel by default...

Comment: For learning purposes you mean compile your own kernel or you just need/want 3.5 kernel?

Comment: i want kernel 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reach the grub menu and see alternate kernels, hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key at boot time. Go to the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" menu.

Also keep in mind that there are [official mainline Ubuntu kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) you can install with dpkg.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest amending your GRUB2 menu to add the option for the alternate kernal. Specific instructions are provided at [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) so you may add the older kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub.cfg
```

and comment out this line:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
```

to:

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
```

This will mean that the menu will show by default, for the time in seconds defined by `GRUB_TIMEOUT`

You might want to change the timeout to this so that it automatically selects the default entry after 5 seconds:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
```

So that it remembers the last selected entry, add in this line:

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=saved
```

and change `GRUB_DEFAULT` to:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

after making any changes, save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then run this to update the changes - this will also scan `/boot` for any new kernels, like the one you installed:

```
sudo update-grub
```

More on editing `grub.cfg` [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration)

Comment: You need a space after the `nano` - `sudo nano /etc/default/grub.cfg`

Comment: after typed the 1st command it displays a blank screen.how to i change the text GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
to:

#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"

Comment: For recent versions of GRUB, the config file should be at `/etc/default/grub`. If you have Grub1, try using `/boot/grub/menu.lst` instead, though I think that use different parameters...

Answer (score 0):

To install the Quantal hardware enablement packages in Precise, please run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack